# MySQL Stored Proc - String param wont work with double quotes but it does with single quotes

Tags: mysql

So my stored proc has a query initially to get a primary key based on a string field being passed in.

```
PROCEDURE `updateAsset`( IN _stringField VARCHAR(250))

DECLARE assetID int(11);
DECLARE assetName varchar(65);

SELECT 
    idAsset, asset_name
INTO assetID , assetName FROM
    Assets
WHERE
    stringField = _stringField
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Now the problem occurs when i call the procedure like so.

```
CALL updateAsset("Rack1");
```

Calling it with double quotes causes the query to not find a match and return the last row inserted into the table.

But if i call the procedure using single quotes, it works.

```
CALL updateAsset('Rack1');
```

I also want to mention that query without `select into` works when ran outside the stored procedure with double or single quotes.

```
SELECT 
    idAsset, asset_name
 FROM
    Assets
WHERE
    stringField = "Rack1"
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

EDIT - Better explanation

The stored proc has been returning the last row of the table without making a match in the where clause.

It simply returns the last row of the table `order by 1 desc limit 1` returns the last row if there wasnt a `where` clause.

Where as the non proc query will find the correct result using the where clause.

Comment: The queries differ by more than just the presence of the INTO clause; `stringField = _stringField` <> `mapplicID = _stringField`, and the ORDER BY is reversed.

Comment: Sorry i changed the column name, mapplicID should of been string field.

Comment: And the idAsset column is the first column of the table so they are both the same. I just copied a query i had up in my workbench. The idea is that "Rack1" doesnt work in the stored proc but 'Rack1' does.

Comment: By default, there is **no difference** between single and double quotes in MySQL, but the `sql_mode` can change that. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html. I suspect there is something about your question that you haven't shared.

Comment: Yes, `SELECT idAsset ... ORDER BY 1` is the same as `SELECT idAssset ... ORDER idAsset`; but your second query specified `DESC` and the first does not (`ASC` is default).

Comment: @Uueerdo ok yes the ordering is incorrect but most of the time these queries should only return 1 result (before limit). Ill explain the problem better in an edit.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have the exact same stored procedure call in workbench, one uses double quotes on the param and the second uses single quotes. Only single quotes works.

Comment: Perhaps adding the table's create statement would help.